# How to programmatically trigger fancybox with an inline div?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to make a fancybox appear when someone tries to submit a form. So I've got this:

```
$('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
    $.fancybox({
        content: '<h2>Hello Fancybox</h2>',
        modal: true
    });
    return false;
});
```

Works good, but I'd rather use my div than trying to specify all the HTML in the content string. Can I make it popup with this

```
<div style="display:none" id="access-policy">
blah blah blah
</div>
```

Instead?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**For FancyBox v3 or later see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42876852/418310)**

**For old versions:**

You need to set in `href` property the div ID. If you use `$('#access-policy').show()` in `content` property the second time you open this fancybox will show nothing.

```
$('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
    $.fancybox({
        href: '#access-policy', 
        modal: true
    });
    return false;
});
```

Also in the HTML has to be:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="access-policy">
        blah blah blah
    </div>
</div>
```

:)

Comment: how can we change href: '#access-policy' dynamically from a variable

Comment: @Wasim It's a string, put the selector you want there :)

Comment: answer is outdated. for new fancybox versions, see `@Michael`-s answer below.

Answer (score 14):

## **The other answers need to be updated**

because I was using the accepted answer's code and was scratching my head for half an hour.

In the most recent FancyBox 3, they have changed some option names and how to use some methods.

The older version on how to open an inline element:

```
$.fancybox({ // OUTDATED
    href: '#element-id', 
    modal: true
});
```

needs to change to

```
$.fancybox.open({ // FancyBox 3
    src: '#element-id', 
    modal: true
});
```

**Notice the open method and the href->src change.**

Without the open you will get a fancybox is not a function error. Without "src" you will get a requested content cannot be loaded popup.

Hope this help someone to avoid my same mistakes and we do need to FOLLOW THE DOCUMENTATION on this one. That's much harder to be outdated.

Comment: if you want a close button just remove the `modal: true` option

Comment: This works for Fancybox 2 or 3: $.fancybox.open($(''#element-id"));

Answer (score 6):

you can do:

```
$('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
    $.fancybox({
        content: $('#access-policy').show(), 
        modal: true
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: answer is outdated. for new fancybox versions, see `@Michael`-s answer below

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind. `content` can be a jquery object:

```
$('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
    $.fancybox({
        content: $('#access-policy'),
        modal: true
    });
    return false;
});
```

But the `div` has to be wrapped in a hidden div,

```
<div style="display:none"><div id="access-policy">
blah blah blah
</div></div>
```

Otherwise nothing will appear; it doesn't change the display property.

Comment: or what you can do is: `$('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
    $.fancybox({
        content: $('#access-policy').show(),
        modal: true
    });
    return false;
});` and still have ur orig div. (ill post this as an answer as well

Answer (score 3):

Content is "any HTML", so get the HTML from the Div and give it to content

```
content: $('#access-policy').html(),
```

Answer (score 2):

This demonstrates how to use fancybox without requiring the `<a href>` link element.

**Inline (1.3.4):**

```
<div id="menuitem" class="menuitem"></div>

<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="dialogContent">
    </div>
</div>

$('#menuitem').click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'type': 'inline',
        'content': '#dialogContent'
    });
});
```

**Inline (2.1.5):**

```
<div id="menuitem" class="menuitem"></div>

<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="dialogContent">
    </div>
</div>

$('#menuitem').click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'type': 'inline',
        'href': '#dialogContent'
    });
});
```

**Iframe**:

```
<div id="menuitem" class="menuitem"></div>

$('#menuitem').click(function () {
    $.fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        href: 'http://www.abc123.com'
    });
});
```

Comment: answer is outdated. for new fancybox versions, see `@Michael`-s answer below