# Magento FancyBox confirmation dialogue

Tags: magento, fancybox

When I add an item to cart from the search results page in Magento it does not display the FancyBox confirmation box. The item DOES get added to the cart though. On the main category page it displays the confirmation box OK upon adding an item to cart.

The JS & CSS for FancyBox are included in both the category and search results pages, I have manually checked in the source.

If I replace

```
jQuery.fancybox.close();
```

with

```
alert(data.message);
```

then it displays a standard Javascript alert saying it's added to cart and shows the correct item details. The FancyBox is preferred though with the product image.

Here's the code for **app\design\frontend\custom_package\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml**, the Javascript is at the end. Thanks for taking a look :D

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $columnCount = themeOptions('column_count');
    $this->setColumnCount($columnCount);
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');   

?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <?php $imgSize = 192; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php include('view/labels.phtml')  ?>   
            <?php $mainImg = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgSize); ?>
            <?php $backImg = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("ajax/listmedia")->setTemplate("catalog/product/list/media.phtml")->setData('size', $imgSize)->setData('product', $_product)->toHtml();  ?>               
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                <?php if($backImg != 'null'): ?><img src="<?php echo $backImg ?>" width="<?php echo $imgSize ?>" height="<?php echo $imgSize ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /><?php endif; ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgSize) ?>" <?php if($backImg != 'null'): ?>onmouseover="hideImage(this)" onmouseout="showImage(this)"<?php endif; ?> width="<?php echo $imgSize ?>" height="<?php echo $imgSize ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
            </a>

             <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div id="productimgover<?php echo $_product->getId()?>" style="display: none;"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(64); ?>" width="64" height="64" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></div>
                    <div id='productname<?php echo $_product->getId()?>' style='display:none'><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></div>
                    <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <?php if(themeOptions('addto')): ?>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="addtocont">
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <?php if ( !($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($_product) || $_product->isGrouped()) ) { ?>
                        <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocationAjax('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>','<?php echo $_product->getId()?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="showOptions('<?php echo $_product->getId()?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                        <a href='<?php echo $this->getUrl('ajax/index/options',array('product_id'=>$_product->getId()));?>' class='fancybox' id='fancybox<?php echo $_product->getId()?>' style="display: none;" ><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></a>
                    <?php }  ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php endif; ?>            
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

    <?php else: ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php 

        $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); 

        if($_columnCount == 4){
            $imgSize = 180;
        }elseif($_columnCount == 3){
            $imgSize = 245;
        }

    ?>

    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid columns<?php echo $_columnCount ?>">
        <?php endif ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php include('view/labels.phtml')  ?>
                <?php $mainImg = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgSize); ?>
                <?php $backImg = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("ajax/listmedia")->setTemplate("catalog/product/list/media.phtml")->setData('size', $imgSize)->setData('product', $_product)->toHtml();  ?>               
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <?php if($backImg != 'null'): ?><img src="<?php echo $backImg ?>" width="<?php echo $imgSize ?>" height="<?php echo $imgSize ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /><?php endif; ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgSize) ?>" <?php if($backImg != 'null'): ?>onmouseover="hideImage(this)" onmouseout="showImage(this)"<?php endif; ?> width="<?php echo $imgSize ?>" height="<?php echo $imgSize ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                </a>

                <div id="productimgover<?php echo $_product->getId()?>" style="display: none;"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(64); ?>" width="64" height="64" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></div>

                <div class="moreinfo">
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                    <div id='productname<?php echo $_product->getId()?>' style='display:none'><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></div>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <?php if ( !($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($_product) || $_product->isGrouped()) ) { ?>
                                <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocationAjax('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>','<?php echo $_product->getId()?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>

                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="showOptions('<?php echo $_product->getId()?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                                <a href='<?php echo $this->getUrl('ajax/index/options',array('product_id'=>$_product->getId()));?>' class='fancybox' id='fancybox<?php echo $_product->getId()?>' style="display: none;" ><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></a>
                            <?php }  ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <?php if(themeOptions('addto')): ?>
                            <ul class="add-to-links">
                                <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                    <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>

    <?php endif; ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox({
            hideOnContentClick : true,
            width: 582,
            autoDimensions: true,
            type : 'iframe',
            showTitle: false,
            scrolling: 'no',
            onComplete: function(){ //Resize the iframe to correct size
            jQuery('#fancybox-frame').load(function() { // wait for frame to load and then gets it's height
                jQuery('#fancybox-content').height(jQuery(this).contents().find('body').height()+30);
                jQuery.fancybox.resize();
             });

            }
        });        
        function showOptions(id){
            jQuery('#fancybox'+id).trigger('click');
        }
        function setAjaxData(data,iframe){
            if(data.status == 'ERROR'){
                alert(data.message);
            }else{
                if(jQuery('.block-cart')){
                    jQuery('.block-cart').replaceWith(data.sidebar);
                }
                if(jQuery('.header .block-cart-header')){
                    jQuery('.header .block-cart-header').replaceWith(data.topcart);
                } 
                jQuery.fancybox.close();
            }
        }
        function setLocationAjax(url,id){
            url += 'isAjax/1';
            url = url.replace("checkout/cart","ajax/index");
            var msgHtml;
            var productImg = jQuery('#productimgover' + id).html();
            var windowOver = jQuery('#addedoverlay');
            var windowBox = jQuery('#added');
            var titleForBox = jQuery('#productname' + id).text();
            windowOver.show();
            windowBox.show().css({
                backgroundImage: "url('<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/loading.gif')?>')"
            });
            try {
                jQuery.ajax( {
                    url : url,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success : function(data) {
                        if(data.status == 'SUCCESS'){    
                            msgHtml = '<div class="added-content"><div style="float:left;">' + productImg + '</div><em>' + titleForBox + '</em> <?php echo $this->__('was successfully added to your shopping cart.') ?><div style="clear:both;"></div><a id="hidewindow" href="javascript:void(0);"><?php echo $this->__('Continue shopping') ?></a>&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart')?>"><?php echo $this->__('View cart & checkout') ?></a></div>';             
                        }else{
                            msgHtml = '<div class="added-content"><p class="error-msg" style="margin-bottom:15px;">' + data.message + '</p><a id="hidewindow" href="javascript:void(0);"><?php echo $this->__('Continue shopping') ?></a>&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart')?>"><?php echo $this->__('View cart & checkout') ?></a></div>';
                        }            
                        setAjaxData(data,false);

                        windowBox.css({
                              backgroundImage: 'none'
                        }).html(msgHtml);                      
                        windowOver.one('click',function(){
                            hidewindow(windowBox,windowOver);                    
                        });        

                        jQuery('#hidewindow').click(function(){
                            hidewindow(windowBox,windowOver);                    
                        });                        
                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
            }
        }
        function hidewindow(windowBox,windowOver){
            windowOver.fadeOut(400);
            windowBox.fadeOut(400).html('');    
        }        
        function hideImage(img){
            jQuery(img).animate({
                'opacity' : 0
            },150);
        }

        function showImage(img){
            jQuery(img).animate({
                'opacity' : 1
            },150);
        }

        </script>
    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Do you have any error in your javascript console?

Comment: TypeError: jQuery.fancybox is undefined 

jQuery.fancybox.close();

Comment: Hiya, if jQuery.fancybox.close(); is replaced with alert(data.message); then there's no error in the console

Comment: When the search results page loads it also shows TypeError: jQuery(...).fancybox is not a function  

onComplete: function(){ //Resize the iframe to correct size

Comment: jQuery.fancybox is not define on the page 1. make sure the js file is included plus jquery.js. 2. take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829319/close-fancy-box-from-function-from-within-open-fancybox

Comment: Hey, now FancyBox is included on the catalogue page, no errors on loading the page in the console, no errors when adding to cart. BUT, it still doesn't display the FancyBox confirmation when Add to Car is clicked :/

Comment: Without seeing the site it hard for me to debug, but do you have a js on click event or after add to cart ajax complete to open up fancy etc? What trigger the code to open up fancyBox and is this code included on the catalogsearch?

Comment: Are you trying to open or close fancybox?

Comment: Trying to open it with a 'Item X added to cart' FancyBox confirmation. The current onClick is onclick="setLocationAjax('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) Apologies for being such a newb

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a lot of code, that i'm not 100% sure what purpose they serve. Take a look @ [fancybox options/apis](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

Try this

```
success : function(data) {
    if(data.status == 'SUCCESS'){    
        msgHtml = '<div class="added-content"><div style="float:left;">' + productImg + '</div><em>' + titleForBox + '</em> <?php echo $this->__('was successfully added to your shopping cart.') ?><div style="clear:both;"></div><a id="hidewindow" href="javascript:void(0);"><?php echo $this->__('Continue shopping') ?></a>&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart')?>"><?php echo $this->__('View cart & checkout') ?></a></div>';             
    }else{
        msgHtml = '<div class="added-content"><p class="error-msg" style="margin-bottom:15px;">' + data.message + '</p><a id="hidewindow" href="javascript:void(0);"><?php echo $this->__('Continue shopping') ?></a>&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart')?>"><?php echo $this->__('View cart & checkout') ?></a></div>';
    } 

    jQuery.fancybox({
         content: msgHtml,
         modal: true
    });           

}
```

See [How to programatically trigger fancybox with an inline div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811415/how-to-programatically-trigger-fancybox-with-an-inline-div)

Also in `function setAjaxData(data,iframe)` on success you seem to be closing the fancybox using `jQuery.fancybox.close();`

Change this

```
<a id="hidewindow" href="javascript:void(0);">?php echo $this->__('Continue shopping') ?>...
```

to (something like)

```
<a href="#" onclick="jQuery.fancybox.close();">...
```

Comment: can you give the path to where the code suppose to be loaded under