# how to actiavte fancybox after submit button pressed or how to let the user show sign up screen using fancybox after submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Desired Operation : User will fill out the html form and when press the submit button then I want to validate the user type and if it is guest then it should show a fancybox(popup) screen to sign up for that user because I dont want to save values with guest user. The code I have mentioned in the question is fine but HOW CAN I ACTIVATE THE FANCYBOX SCREEN AFTER VALIDATING THE USER.

I am trying

```
if($_SESSION['FIRST_NAME']=="Guest")
{
// here I want the code to show the signup.php page
print '<a id="loginframe" href="Signup.php">Sign Up here</a>';
}
```

How would I activate the fancybox screen coz I dont want to show the link but the activated fancybox firectly with the signup.php iframe. (fancybox is working fine)

Comment: You can use `$array[index]` without quotes though I personally would not recommend doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, I suggest that you avoid using iframes in this particular case.

What I would do is use AJAX to submit the form. That way, the page will not be reloaded and you'll have a js callback function where you can trigger Fancybox. ([Jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [jQuery Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/))

Here is how you can programatically trigger Fancybox:

[How to programatically trigger fancybox with an inline div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811415/how-to-programatically-trigger-fancybox-with-an-inline-div)

I hope this helps.